# Apply a shadow to an array of UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, shadow

I have an array of `UIImageViews`. I want to apply a shadow to each of these images. I've used the code below:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    for (UIImageView *image in imagesJigsawPieces) {
        image.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        image.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, -1);
        image.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
        image.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
        image.clipsToBounds = NO; //EDIT: I have also included this with no change
    }
}
```

I have also included `#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>`.

I am not getting any errors but I am also not getting any shadows on my images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain this code is being called? Have you placed a breakpoint in the `for` loop to verify?

`-awakeFromNib` is called only if you have a view (or whatever) in a nib file connected via `IBOutlet` to an ivar in your code. `-awakefFromNib` is called, in this case, *instead* of `-initWithFrame:` (or the like), an important distinction which I sometimes forget myself!

Comment: Thank you, i don't how i missed. I wasn't calling the code correctly - it's all working now. Thanks again.